# Can I reuse the same buffer for subsequent itoa() calls?

Tags: c++, buffer, itoa

I'm wondering if this is safe/sanctioned usage:

```
char pBuf[10];
itoa(iInt, pBuf, 10);
// pBuf value gets copied elsewhere

//memset(pBuf, 0, sizeof(pBuf)); // Is this necessary?
itoa(iInt2, pBuf, 10);
// pBuf value gets copied elsewhere
```

Can I reuse the buffer like this?

Comment: What did you experience when doing so? I can't spot any UB.

Comment: Yes you can (the memset is not necessary)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is safe.

`itoa` will just overwrite the memory, and insert a null terminator at the end. It is this null terminator which makes it safe (assuming of course that your array is large enough)

Consider the following:

```
int iInt = 12345;
char pBuf[10];
itoa(iInt, pBuf, 10);
```

At this point, `pBuf` will look something like this in memory:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----------------------------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | \0 | ... unintialised memory ... |
+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----------------------------+
```

Then you re-use `pBuf`:

```
int iInt2 = 5;    
itoa(iInt2, pBuf, 10);
```

Now `pBuf` will look like something this in memory:

```
+---+----+---+---+---+----+-----------------------------+
| 5 | \0 | 3 | 4 | 5 | \0 | ... unintialised memory ... |
+---+----+---+---+---+----+-----------------------------+
       ^
       |
       +---- note the null terminator
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. No need to `memset()`, `itoa()` will overwrite.

Also make sure your buffer is large enough to fit the value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can call `itoa` twice using the same buffer. Memset is also not necessary, because `itoa` makes no assumptions about the buffer being empty.

Also note that `10` characters is not long enough for `itoa`, the string representing a 4 bytes int can be as long as 11 characters + `\0` terminator, totalling 12 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice: **Don't use it at all**, this function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers.

Use `std::to_string` instead. (to keep in mind, std::to_string may yield unexpected results when used with floating point types and the return values may be substantially different from what std::cout would print)

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I did end up just using `to_string` instead.

Comment: if that helped, don't forget to accept the answer, please . Thanks

Comment: It was helpful though it wasn't a direct answer to the question technically.